# JS making a forEach match more efficient

Tags: javascript

`variants` is an object of objects and `selectedOptions` is an object of option1, option2, option3. The below `forEach` searches through the `variants` to find a match.

Is there a more efficient way, using an array method or similar, to do the following:

```
Object.values(variants).forEach(variant => {
    if (variant.options.option1 === selectedOptions.option1 && variant.options.option2 === selectedOptions.option2 && variant.options.option3 === selectedOptions.option3) {
        selectedVariant = variant.gid;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not try filter...

Comment: please show sample data for variant and selectedOptions

Comment: Oooooor `Array#find`? `const selectedVariant = Object.values(variants).find(variant => variant.options.option1 === selectedOptions.option1 && variant.options.option2 === selectedOptions.option2 && variant.options.option3 === selectedOptions.option3
).gid;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you're doing here is loop through all the variants, overwriting `selectedVariant` each time you find a match. And if there's supposed to be only one match, you still visit all the other variants when there's no need for it anymore.

More efficient would be:

```
selectedVariant = Object.values(variants).find(variant => (
    variant.options.option1 === selectedOptions.option1 && 
    variant.options.option2 === selectedOptions.option2 &&
    variant.options.option3 === selectedOptions.option3
)).gid;
```

That way you stop the moment you find a match.

And to be perfectly honest, setting a variant equal to another variant's gid looks wrong. Either name the variable you assign to `selectedVariantGid`, or assign the entire variant, and later use the `.gid` property once you need it. Clear naming is important.

Comment: Also, if he actually wants the last matching item in the array, which is what his code effectively does, he can reverse the array before find: `Object.values(variants).slice().reverse().find(variant => ...` (`slice()` as to not affect the original array)

Comment: True, but since he gets the original array from `Object.values()`, I suspect order is not that important, and any match will do. I certainly wouldn't know off the top of my head in what order `Object.values()` returns those values, so I wouldn't put too much trust in that order. If order is important, make it explicit.

Comment: Agreed, I just wanted to mention it as a way to replicate the exact same result from any given input.